# Where to locate a spring database XML file in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I got the following situation in Spring.

a spring-database.xml file (with hibernate beans, sessionfactory, dao, etc.) in src/main/java and some subfolders.
I haven't been able to make it work with logging users saved in MySQL tables.

So I moved spring-database.xml under WEB-INF and here it worked.
Problem is that now I don't know how to call it from java code with:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext([PATH I DON'T KNOW])
```

because this doesn't work and I need some beans from that file, which are not found now.
I also tried FileSystemXmlApplicationContext instead of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext with no results.

1. What's the best solution to locate this xml file? under src/main/java or under WEB-INF?
2. And how to call its beans correctly without messing around with relative/absolute paths?

Answer (score 0):

ideally you should make two xml files

```
1. mvc-config.xml or your spring-database.xml (with hibernate, sessionfactory etc)
2.application-config.xml(this should contain all the bean relates info that you should need in your project.)
```

Keep the mvc-config.xml in your WEB-INF/ folder and apllication-config.xml in classpath.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
   classpath:spring/application-config.xml,
   /WEB-INF/conf/mvc-config.xml 
  </param-value>
 </context-param>
```

This is how you load both in the web.xml
You will be able to get the application.xml from the above code you are trying.

[Look at this example.](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/02/maven-spring-mvc-hibernate-sitemesh-hello-world-project.html)